# How can a car device convert 12V to 220V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, charger

I found on Amazon a device like this that can convert from the 12V power supply of a car to 220V to connect a laptop charger to the socket of this adapter.

How can a device convert something with only 12V input and output 220V? How can it be possible?

[image: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61zYa3ECQqL.SS350_AC.jpg]

Comment: Magic and sorcery.

Comment: Check out the voltage of the spark plugs that are also powered by that 12v.

Comment: How can it be possible that radio works; what manner of witchcraft could that be?

Answer (score 3):

That is an inverter. There are multiple ways how it can convert 12V DC to 220V AC.

It can first step up the voltage and then output it as AC with an H-bridge, or it can first use the 12V to generate 12V AC with H-bridge and then step up the voltage with a transformer.

Comment: Okay, but how can we add any voltage from a 12V AC input to a 220V AC output with a transformer ? whereas we have only 12V existing in entry, I don't find how we can "add" electricity voltage ?

Comment: Transformers can be used to step down or step up voltage, there's no rule that allows them to only step voltage down. That's how high voltage electricity distribution networks work, voltage is stepped up near generators to tens or hundreds of kilovolts and then stepped down near consumers.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. A simplified inverter schematic. Image source: [ElecCircuit](https://www.eleccircuit.com/how-to-build-the-200-watts-home-inverter-projects/).*

How it works:

- Q1 is turned on. Current flows from +12V through CT (centre-tap) to the top of the transformer.
- Q1 is turned off.
- Q2 is turned on. Current flows from +12V through CT (centre-tap) to the bottom of the transformer.
- Q2 is turned off.

The result is pulses of current running in alternate directions in the transformer primary. The transformer will have a turns ration of roughly 12:240 (1:20) and the output voltage will be close to 220 V and alternate at the same rate as the primary.

The output waveform probably won't resemble a sinewave very closely as there are no filters and no modulation of the primary current to try to achieve a better output waveform.

Answer (score 0):

Inverters work by changing electricity while maintaining power. Some power is "lost" by converting to heat (the efficiency of the circuit). Electricity isn't just the voltage involved but also the current. So as long as you meet both needs, you have not created power, just changed it. This keeps it in line with the laws of thermodynamics.

By taking 12V DC and pulsing it to make it an AC wave, sending that into a transformer wired to increase the voltage, you convert the 12V DC in 220V AC, which goes through other conditioning circuitry for the output. But the current/wattage available will depend on the input current. A typical car 12V outlet is fused for 10 amps or 120 Watts, so the maximum you can expect to get on a car inverter output is 120V 1 Amp (minus efficiency/conversion penalties). Or 240V 0.5 Amps. Both of which are still 120 Watts.